# Bluebird Promises with Event Emitter

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I am fairly new with using Bluebird promises. I was trying to use them over an emitter. However, I am stuck on how to handle errors.

I have a `stream` object which is the emitter. Code is as below -

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var onDocFunc = doc => {
        //JSON.parse('*');
        // some logic goes in here to construct setStmt
        bulk.find(query).upsert().update({$set: setStmt});
        count++;
        if (count % bulkSize == 0) {
            stream.pause();
            var execute = Promise.promisify(bulk.execute);
            execute().catch(() => {}).then(() => {
                stream.resume();
            });
        }
    };

    stream.on('data', onDocFunc);

    stream.on('end', () => {
        JSON.parse('*'); // how to catch errors that happen here??
        var boundResolve = resolve.bind(this, {count: count});
        if (count % bulkSize != 0) {
            Promise.promisify(bulk.execute)().then(boundResolve).catch(boundResolve);
        }
        else {
            boundResolve();
        }
    });

    stream.on('error', err => {
        reject(err);
    });

})
```

I want to know what is the recommended way to catch an error which occurs inside the callback of the `end` event handler? Right now if any error occurs, the NodeJS application crashes with `uncaughtException: Unexpected token *`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix application logic into the promisification of the event emitter. Such code (that can throw etc) should always go in `then` callbacks. In your case:

```
var execute = Promise.promisify(bulk.execute);
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stream.on('data', onDocFunc); // not sure what this does
    stream.on('end', resolve);
    stream.on('error', reject);
}).then(() => {
    JSON.parse('*'); // exceptions that happen here are caught implicitly!
    var result = {count: count};
    if (count % bulkSize != 0) {
        return execute().catch(()=>{}).return(result);
    } else {
        return result;
    }
});
```

---

Regarding your real code, I'd probably try to factor out the batching into a helper function:

```
function asyncBatch(stream, size, callback) {
    var batch = [], count = 0;
    stream.on('data', data => {
        batch.push(data);
        count++;
        if (batch.length == size) {
            stream.pause();
            Promise.resolve(batch).then(callback).then(() => {
                batch = [];
                stream.resume();
            }, e => {
                stream.emit('error', e);
            });
        }
    });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stream.on('end', resolve);
        stream.on('error', reject);
    }).then(() => batch.length ? callback(batch) : null).then(() => count);
}

Promise.promisifyAll(Bulk);
return asyncBatch(stream, bulkSize, docs => {
    const bulk = new Bulk()
    for (const doc of docs) {
        // JSON.parse('*');
        // some logic goes in here to construct setStmt
        bulk.find(query).upsert().update({$set: setStmt});
    }
    return bulk.executeAsync().catch(err => {/* ignore */});
})
```

Comment: This looks neat. Thanks for the insights. Will keep this in mind.

Comment: If I have to handle exceptions like the `JSON.parse` inside `onDocFunc` what should I do?

Comment: Go for `try`-`catch` blocks then, although I'm not convinced you actually *need* the `JSON.parse` in there. If you could post the whole code of what you are actually doing in your question, I can update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a try/catch block:

```
stream.on('end', () => {
  try {
    JSON.parse('*')
    // ...the rest of your code
  } catch (e) {
    reject(e)
  }
})
```

Comment: Yea even I thought of `try-catch`. However, using it makes the code a bit messy, since I have to now start enclosing all callbacks with these blocks. Is this the only way to deal with such situation?

Comment: @hyades well what you should probably do is resolve whatever data you have immediately in the 'end' event callback. Then add a `.then()` handler to your promise and do the `JSON.parse()` stuff inside there. Then any errors will be "caught" and cause the returned promise to become rejected.

Comment: Yeah, just do what @bergi said.