# Async/await with event-stream mapSync not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, event-stream

The `await` commands that I have commented with `//******This await does not work */` do not seem to work. Not sure if this is something related to the fact they are in an event stream or a problem with the promise in the imported module.

When I call the `run` function from within a mapped array to insert data from multiple sources, the `run` function returns immediately rather than waiting until `knex` has completed inserting the data.

```
 app.get("/api/pull/all_data", (req, res)=>{
    const dataSources = [
      {resource: 'DI_ORDER_TYPE', tableName: 'ln_order_type'},
      {resource: 'DI_DATES', tableName: 'ln_dates'},
      {resource: 'WHINR140_INVENTORY', tableName: 'ln_inventory'}
    ]

    dataSources.map(async (ds)=>{
      console.log(`Importing ${ds.resource} into table ${ds.tableName}`)
      await get_all_data(ds.tableName, ds.resource)
    })

    console.log("Import complete")
  })
```

Here is my `run` function which is being called from the code above.

```
const request = require('request')
const JSONStream = require('JSONStream')
const es = require('event-stream')
const knex_ln = require('../knex_ln')
const insertData = require('../insert_data')
const create_table = require('../create_table_from_json.js')
const clean_fieldnames = require('../clean_fieldnames')

function run(tableName, resourceName) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject)=>{
        let tableData = []
        let recordCount = 0
        let maxRecords = 10000
        let totalRecords = 0
        // let tableName = 'LN_di_order_type'
        // let resourceName = 'DI_ORDER_TYPE'
        let rowData = {}
        //Delete Existing Data and wait for it to complete
        await knex_ln.schema.hasTable(tableName).then(async (exists)=>{
            if(exists){
                try {
                    await knex_ln(tableName).delete().then(()=>{})
                } catch (error) {
                    
                }
            }
        })
        //Get LN replica data and pipe data into JSONStream
        request(`${process.env.API_BASE_URL}/${process.env.SECURITY_NAME}/${resourceName}`,
        {
            auth: {
                'user': process.env.API_USER,
                'pass': process.env.API_PASS
            }
        }
        )
        .pipe(JSONStream.parse([true, {recurse: true}, `${process.env.SECURITY_NAME}.row`, true]))
        .pipe(es.mapSync(async (row)=>{
            rowData = row
            let cleanData = await clean_fieldnames(row)
            tableData.push(cleanData)
            recordCount += 1
            totalRecords += 1
            if(recordCount >= maxRecords){
                try {
                    //******This await does not work */
                    await create_table(tableName, row)
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log("Unable to create table", error)
                }
               
                //Insert records
                try {
                    //******This await does not work */
                    await insertData(tableName, tableData)
                    console.log(`inserting ${recordCount} records into table ${tableName}`)
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log("Unable to insert data: ", error)
                }
               
                //Reset tracker variables
                recordCount = 0
                tableData = []
            }
        }))
        .on('end', async ()=>{
            await create_table(tableName, rowData)
            await insertData(tableName, tableData)
            console.log(`Inserted ${totalRecords} into table ${tableName}`)
            resolve('OK')
        })
        .on('error',(err)=>{
            reject(err)
        })
    })
}
module.exports = run
```

Here is my module file which returns a promise

```
//insert_data.js
const knex_ln = require('./knex_ln')

module.exports = async (tableName, tableData) => 
    new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        await knex_ln(tableName).insert(tableData)
        console.log("Inserting Data: ", tableData.length)
        resolve()
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error inserting data: ", err)
        reject(err)
      }
    })
```

Here is an example of the output

```
Importing DI_ORDER_TYPE into table ln_order_type
Importing DI_DATES into table ln_dates
Importing WHINR140_INVENTORY into table ln_inventory
Importing WHWMD210_WAREHOUSE_ITEM_DATA into table ln_warehouse_item_data
Importing TDIPU010_ITEM_BUY_FROM_BP_INFORMATION into table ln_item_buy_from_bp_information
Importing TDIPU001_ITEM_PURCHASE_DATA into table ln_item_purchase_data
Importing TDPCG031_PRICE_BOOKS into table ln_price_books
Importing TDPUR300_PURCHASE_CONTRACTS into table ln_purchase_contracts
Importing TDPUR301_PURCHASE_CONTRACT_LINES into table ln_purchase_contract_lines
Inserted 72 records into table ln_order_type
Inserted 217 records into table ln_purchase_contracts
inserting 10000 records into table ln_inventory
Inserted 4694 records into table ln_purchase_contract_lines
inserting 10000 records into table ln_item_buy_from_bp_information
inserting 10000 records into table ln_dates
inserting 10000 records into table ln_inventory
inserting 10000 records into table ln_price_books
inserting 10000 records into table ln_item_purchase_data
inserting 10000 records into table ln_inventory
inserting 10000 records into table ln_price_books
inserting 10000 records into table ln_dates
inserting 10000 records into table ln_inventory
inserting 10000 records into table ln_price_books
inserting 10000 records into table ln_item_purchase_data
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What exactly is it doing? What do you expect it to do that it isn't? Can you cut the code sample down to something smaller that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: It's difficult to cut it down without loosing context. As I said in the question "When I call the run function from within a mapped array to insert data from multiple sources, the run function returns immediately rather than waiting until knex has completed inserting the data."

Comment: Never ever pass `async` functions as callbacks - not to `new Promise`, not to `on`, not to `then`, not to `map`*`Sync`*.

Comment: @Bergi I think now my problem is related to needing to promisify the (end) event for the stream. Not sure of how to do that.

Comment: @PrestonDocks [Pretty simple actually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40707973/1048572). You should however place *only* the `on("end", resolve)` etc handlers inside the `new Promise` constructor, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to use bluebird Promise.each

This will process each of the items in array dataSources and wait for the promise to return before processing the next item in the list.

```
Promise.each(dataSources, function(ds){
     ....
    }).then(()=>{
     ....
    })
```

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html

Answer (score 1):

I Implemented my own Writable implementation. I could control the calls in sequence with help of callback function .Only when the callback is received from the previous iteration the next iteration is processed . I was not able to achieve this using event-stream map callback

Reference https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_simplified_construction

```
      readStream.pipe(eventStream.split())
            .pipe(
                 new Writable({
                    write : async (record, encoding,callback)=>{
                               await saveToDatabase(record);
                               callback();
                        }
                })
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only awaiting on the inner functions in the `map` and not the top-level function.

You need to add an await to the top-level function:

```
await Promise.all(dataSources.map(async (ds)=> {
  console.log(`Importing ${ds.resource} into table ${ds.tableName}`)
  await get_all_data(ds.tableName, ds.resource)
}));
```

Otherwise, you're only waiting in the internal function and not in the route handler itself.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working even with await Promise.all(). I have added an example of the output to the bottom of my question. This is after adding the Promise.all().

Comment: This doesn't suit the situation. Because here the await is dishonoured completely inside the function

Comment: @AbdulSaleem it's not, because of the `map` going over the array of promises and waiting for it with `await`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I also thought just like that and found some very strange behaviour when I run. For me, this thing happened first time and only inside JSONStream and was very strange. What I ended up was with some kind of hack to get it working.